# FastAPI: throw Error->"msg": "str type expected", "type": "type_error.str"

Tags: fastapi

I am tryting to upload 2 images and some detail info of Banner(ex:id,title,subtitle,desc...).
I used Form,UploadFile,When i use Schema model ,it throw an error.
if i single input per attribute,it's work,how to fix it? Thanks.

schema model:

```
class BannerInputSchema(BaseModel):
    """Banner Create Model"""
    title: str
    sub_title: str | None = None
    path_url: str | None = None
    desc: str | None = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

router:

```
@router.put('/update_banner/{id}',
            response_model=ResponseSchema,
            response_model_exclude_none=True)
async def update_banner(
        banner_id: str = Form(),
        banner_info: BannerInputSchema = Form(),
        b_img: UploadFile = File(default=None, description='upload background img'),
        f_img: UploadFile = File(default=None, description='upload front img'),
):
    result = await BannerService.update_banner(
        banner_id=banner_id,
        banner_info=banner_info,
        b_img=b_img,
        f_img=f_img,
    )

    return ResponseSchema(detail='Success Banner Data', result=result)
```

When i Execute update data,throw 422 Error:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "banner_info",
        "title"
      ],
      "msg": "str type expected",
      "type": "type_error.str"
    }
  ]
}
```

how to fix it?

Comment: You can't give a model as a `Form()` result - regular Form data isn't structured in that way. You can define a class/function that have the `Form` entries as arguments instead, and then make that function return a dict for example (instead of creating a pydantic model).

Comment: @MatsLindh if use body()? have a same result?

Comment: If you use `Body` that is meant to represent a JSON value in the body. If you're submitting JSON, you can map that to a pydantic model. You can't use `Body` together with form-data.